# Azure Service Bus and Xamarin.Android MessageHandler

Tags: xamarin.android, azureservicebus

I am trying to use the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus on a Xamarin.Android mobile application.  I would like to subscribe the device to a specific queue and have it continually monitor that queue for any messages.

I was able to find an article to send a message to a queue, but I am having the hardest time finding a way to subscribe to the queue.  Using the following code doesn't seem to be working.

QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, requestQueueName);

```
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
```

Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Thanks Jlimited

Comment: For the publish and subscribe, you could check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions

Comment: Wendy, I have used this article to connect console applications and websites to service bus.  It works well.  The issue that I am having is trying to connect a Xamarin.android device to the service bus.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting the `TransportType` to `AmqpWebSockets`.  Android can sometimes have issues when the default TCP transport is used.  Since you're not registering an error handler, you wouldn't be observing any exceptions from connection failures.

The easiest way to integrate this into your current snippet would be using the [ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringbuilder):

```cs
var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
builder.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;

var queueClient = new QueueClient(builder.ToString(), requestQueueName);
```

If this is new development with no existing investment in the legacy Service Bus library, you may want to consider using the current generation, [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus).  It's [ServiceBusProcessor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample04_Processor.md) offers the push-based model that you're using with support for specifying your message handling options and also registering an error handler, which the legacy client does not.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75023891/azure-service-bus-the-connection-string-used-for-an-service-bus-client-must-spe