# Azure Service Bus: The connection string used for an Service Bus client must specify the Service Bus namespace host and either a Shared Access Key

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Why is my RootManageSharedAccessKey Connection String Invalid?

**Code:**

When executing the code below, I receive an error about an invalid connection string:

```
serviceBusClient <- new ServiceBusClient(connectionString)
```

**Error:**

> System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not
> implemented.'
>
> System.ArgumentException: 'The connection string used for an Service
> Bus client must specify the Service Bus namespace host and either a
> Shared Access Key (both the name and value) OR a Shared Access
> Signature to be valid. Parameter name: connectionString'

[image]

**ConnectionString:**

```
"Endpoint=sb://myNameSpace.servicebus.windows.net/;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=*******************************************="
```

I also tried removing the *TransportType* property from the connection string:

```
"Endpoint=sb://myNameSpace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=*******************************************="
```

The connection string was derived from the Shared Access Policy of my Service Bus resource:

[image]

**Context:**

Xamarin.Forms (Android)

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

**NuGet Packages:**

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus (7.11.1)
Xamarin.Forms (5.0.0.2545)

Comment: Both connection string examples above are well-formed and valid for use.  I'm able to use them to create a `ServiceBusClient` and parse with `ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties` in both C# and F#.     The "TransportType" token is not valid but is silently ignored.

Comment: I wonder if the client being mobile is the issue. In my case, I'm trying to run the code on Xmarin.Android.

Comment: Connection string parsing is straightforward string slicing.  I can't rule it out, but it seems unlikely.  I'll try to repro on a Xamarin project tomorrow.    What is interesting to me above is the `NotImplementedException` that is in your error details above.  That seems like it may be platform-related, though probably not from the parser.   Do you, by chance, have a stack trace for that one you can share?

Comment: In case you were curious about the details, connection string parsing happens here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Primitives/ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties.cs#L218

Comment: @JesseSquire -   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetSources () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource.cs:318 
  at Azure.Core.Diagnostics.AzureEventSource.DeduplicateName (System.String eventSourceName) [0x00010] in <287460e758c24a47ba03a248ab1a62d9>:0

Comment: Thanks.   Can you confirm package versions for me, as well?   The event source error looks mighty familiar and seems to match one that was fixed a year ago.   (which I see you were involved in the discussion for) 

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24055

Comment: @JesseSquire - Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.11.1, Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250911/discussion-between-jesse-squire-and-scott-nimrod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may be interested, the root cause of this turned out to be that the connection string passed to `ServiceBusClient` was JSON-encoded, causing two quote literals to be embedded.   As a result, there was no `Endpoint=` token present *(it was `"Endpoint=`)* which left the client unable to determine where to connect to.